# Can't access a virtual machine which runs as a service

Tags: windows, batch, services, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to start a virtual machine (I'm using VMware Workstation 7) as a service on my Windows 7 system, so that it starts automatically with my (physical) host.

I used **instsrv** and **srvany.exe** from the Windows Resource Kit to create a new service. This service runs a batch file when Windows is booting.

Thats the content of the batch file:

```
vmrun start "D:\Windows 7 VM\Windows 7.vmx"
```

Well, everything works fine. After logging in to my Windows 7 system, the virtual machine is already running. 
The only problem is, that I can't access to the virtual machine.

After starting VMware Workstation 7, it tells me, that my VM is running but I can't access it.
If I try to open the virtual machine I receive an error message, which tells me that I have to **take ownership** of this virtual machine.

I tried to remove the .lock files and xxx-lock directory but nothing changed.

What else can I try to open my virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could switch over to using [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html) (free), as it's intended to run VM's in the background on a host OS (as a service).

You then access them using the VMware Remote Console, or the VI Web Access, vSphere client, etc.